# Show $L:=\mathbb{Q}_{2}[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}]$ is completely ramified.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This equivalent to $f(x)=x^{4}-2x^2 +3$ being Eiseinstein. We have $|1|_{2}=1$, $|2|_{2}=2^{-1}$ and $|3|=|1|$. So 3 is a 2-adic unit. Thus, f is not Eisenstein and so L is not completely ramified. Where is my mistake?

2) Next is showing that $1,\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}},\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{-2}}$ is a basis for ring of integers $O_{L}$. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Neither $1$ nor $\sqrt{-2}$ are roots of $f(x)$.

Comment: Also $1$ is *always* a unit, not a prime.

Comment: Agree. But then how can L be completely ramified? Where is the mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that this is true for quadratic fields over rationals"? In particular, what is "this"?

Comment: I was editing it. Now is fixed.

Comment: I don't think $L$ is Galois.